# How to get different output files for different rules on snakemake

Tags: python, hpc, snakemake

I am trying to make a snakefile for easy parallelization of various functions. I would like to make one snake file that outputs files to different directories with different names, even though the steps are not necessarily sequential.

```
GENES=['A','B','C']

rule all:
    input:
        expand(join(RESULTS_DIR,"{gene}.rds"), gene=GENES)

rule essentiality:
    group: "essentiality"
    input:
        ESSENTIALITY_SCREEN
    params:
        "{gene}"
    output:
        join(RESULTS_DIR,"Essentiality/{gene}_essentiality.rds")
    shell:
        "Rscript ~/src/essentiality.R --debug --screen {input} --gene_a {params} --data_slots mrna,scna --output_file {output} --q2"

rule drug_screen:
    group: "drug_screen"
    input:
        DRUG_SCREEN
    params:
        "{gene}"
    output:
        join(RESULTS_DIR,"Drug_Screen/{gene}_drug_screen.rds")
    shell:
        "Rscript ~/src/drug_screen.R --debug --screen {input} --gene_a {params} --data_slots mrna,scna --output_file {output}"
```

The problem is that I want *rule essentiality* to have a **different output file name** than rule *drug_screen*. However, rule all requires me to pick one or the other (the way it is currently formatted gives the the error `Missing input files for rule all:` understandably because it needs to match the other rule output).

Is there away around this so both of my rules produce diffrent output names?

Comment: Which files do you want this pipeline to produce? Put these files under rule `all` and then add rules to make these files. At the moment it is not clear to me what it is you want... As you noticed, the files you have in rule `all` don't have rules to produce them. Either edit the rule `all` or add rules to make them.

Comment: Can I have multiple output files under rule all?

Comment: Yes, and you already have multiple output files in rule `all`. `expand(... gene=GENES)` is the same as `['A.rds', 'B.rds', 'C.rds']` and the same as `a= 'A.rds', \\ b= 'B.rds', \\ c= 'C.rds'` (`\\\` meaning newline here, which I cannot write in comment)